# Can I do transfer operation in transfer queue and graphics queue at the same time?

Tags: vulkan

I have made 2 instances of VkQueue: one from graphics family and another one from transfer family. Command pools and command buffers are separated accordingly. Both are doing transfer operations.

- Purpose of first one except rendering is to update uniform buffers on
  each frame.
- Purpose of second one is to update resources: model
  vertex/index buffers, texture images etc.

They work in parallel in different threads asynchronously. So it is possible that there will be 2 calls of vkQueueSubmit at the same time.

Is such usage allowed and is it safe?

Note: once I have multithreaded my program sometimes I have VK_DEVICE_LOST on vkQueueSumbit and it is likely that it happens more frequently when resources are loading, that is why I actually came to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vulkan specification is pretty clear about CPU synchronization of Vulkan functions. [`vkQueueSubmit` says](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.2-extensions/man/html/vkQueueSubmit.html):

> Host access to `queue` **must** be externally synchronized

Where "`queue`" is the parameter passed to `vkQueueSubmit`. It doesn't say *every queue*; it says "that `queue`".

And if "external synchronization" is not specifically stated as a requirement of a command, then it isn't a requirement of that command.